# How to sync source code and/or binaries for multiple repositories

Tags: git, dependency-management, package-managers

I am looking for a tool (package/dependency manager?) to help synchronize code and/or binaries while developing/testing/debugging a project that is split across several repositories.

**Initial Conditions**
 - I have a project that is split across three repositories that all use different languages.
 - One only runs on windows, the others are OS agnostic.
 - Versions are tagged
 - Binaries are built on CI and can be made available however needed

**Goals and Requirements**
- Given a version of repository A, I want to get either the source code or the binary for/from repositories B and/or C
- A way to define which versions of A, B and C are compatible
- Works on Windows, macOS and Linux

Answer (score -1):

There are a handful of different tools available, but you probably want to look into [`dep`](https://github.com/golang/dep) which is on track to become the official dependency management tool for `go`.

See the [`dep` roadmap](https://github.com/golang/dep/wiki/Roadmap) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my problem is cross language and only one of the repositories contains Go code.

Edit: I removed the Go tag from the initial question